# An "if and only if" proof regarding upper bounds

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

Is my proof okay? If not, what should I change?

[image]

Comment: This statement is confusing, because here one should think about $\varepsilon$ as being arbitrarily **large**. The proof can be good if you give explanations to these implications.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, the first if and only if is by definition so it needs no explanation. The second if and only if is true, but you didn't prove why (that * you put shows that you get the idea, that you can always choose $\varepsilon$ such that $u=S+\varepsilon$ but that's not a real proof).

Comment: What would I need to change in order to make it a real proof? What makes this one not sufficient?

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: Off topic, but you should write your proof like a human if what you have written is what you plan to turn in (I think this is homework). It is bad writing practice to use logic symbols in place of English, except of course in the context of formal logic where the symbolic strings are the objects of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write down one of the implications properly:

You want to show that the first statement (Let me call it $P1$)

$$\forall_{u\in \mathbb{R}} \exists_{x\in A} : x>u$$

Is equivalent to the second statement (P2)

$$\forall_{\varepsilon>0} \exists_{x\in A} : x>S+\varepsilon$$

This is how you prove that $P1\Rightarrow P2$:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be any real number. Choose $u=S+\varepsilon$ then by (P1) we know that there exists $x\in A$ such that $x>u$, hence $x>S+\varepsilon$.

Thus, we showed that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x\in A$ such that $x>S+\varepsilon$ (which is exactly (P2)).

I leave the case $P2\Rightarrow P1$ to you.

Comment: I understand this is what I tried to do. I don't understand what do I need to do to make it sufficient.

Comment: Just prove the $P_2\Rightarrow P_1$ similarly to my proof for the other direction and you're done.

Comment: Alright, so the problem with what I did initially is that I showed only a single direction?

Comment: No, you didn't prove formally any of the directions. I post the answer as an example to how you prove formally the first direction.